# Get unique string in imacros Javascript

Tags: javascript, unique, imacros

Suppose I have a string "1,2,1,2,2,3,4", now I want to get unique from this such that My **output** looks like `1,2,3,4`
I have tried with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=class:type-txt<sp>icon-txt&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET ag EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('BHK')[0].replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1');")
PROMPT {{ag}}
```

This is the [link](https://www.proptiger.com/mumbai/thane-west/godrej-greenview-housing-emerald-1405294) of website from where I extract data

The o\p  of "ag" is `1,1,2,1,1,2,3`

Is there any way by which it could be solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Split string using delimiter(`,`) to get array of values.
- Loop over this array.
- Concat string to an empty string to create your final string.
- Check if the value exists in your final string.

  - If yes, do not concat.
  - If no, concat it.
- Return this final string.

For ease in manipulation, I have added `,<value>` and then displayed string from 1 index,

```js
let str =  "1,2,1,2,2,3,4";

let result = str.split(',').reduce(function(p, c){
  if(p.indexOf(c) < 0) {
    p += ',' + c
  }
  return p;
}, '');

console.log(result.substring(1));
```

Comment: Worked fine with me..much Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```js
let str =  "1,2,1,2,2,3,4";

let result = Object.keys(str.split(',').reduce((a, b) => (a[b] = true, a), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Explanation, I used the fact that the keys of an object would be unique, so after splitting the string, I just created an object with those elements as properties, the keys would all be unique.

You can also try

```js
let str = "1,2,1,2,2,3,4";

let result = Array.from(new Set(str.split(',')));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you explain the arrow function (a, b) => (a[b] = true, a)

Comment: I used an arrow function, (a[b] = true, a) would set the property b as true in the object a. **,** just signifies that the return value would be the object a

Comment: Nice didn't know that format, do you have a link were explains that return statement with the comma...

Comment: @marvel308 This is why I keep asking people to add explanation.

Comment: added an easier answer as well, using sets

Comment: for the one liner +1 and using `Set`.. worked well in my case. thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you can take advantage of the spread operator:

```
var myString = "1,2,1,2,2,3,4";
var output = [... new Set(myString)] // [1,2,3,4]
```

If you want the output to be a string:

```
output.join(); // "1,2,3,4"
```

Comment: If you have `([1,2,1,2,2,3,4])`, whats the point of having `myString`? Also, please notice `<>` icon in editor

Comment: My bad, fixed the missed variable. Although there's no need for a runnable snippet here I think...